Why do many software distributions include api-ms-win-core-*.dll and api-ms-win-crt-*.dll?
I found that some software distributions, e.g. Tencent QQ 9.9.9_240401 and Firefox 112.0 (many applications actually), include api-ms-win-core-*.dll and api-ms-win-crt-*.dll, but some do not.
api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll
api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll

My questions are:

Why these software need them? (Not all windows programs require these DLLs.)

What is the purpose of these DLLs? (Any technique behind them?)


Thanks.
P.s. I'm sorry, it's been a long time since I've done Windows programming, so these DLLs are a bit new to me.


why software need DLLs (win/nt api) at all ? ALL software need it. only some software use legacy/classic names as kernel32.dll and some use this names (begin from 8.1) 2) export some functions -like and kernel32, kernelbase,advapi32 and so on


So they can be installed on XP or Server2003.  If you have a recent Win10 SDK installed then you'll find them back in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs.   The normal distribution of the UCRT is through Windows Update, supporting users that don't keep their machine updated is, erm, courageous.

These are part of the C runtime library.
Developers have the option to ship them with their application to avoid dll-hell.

Windows API sets
The purpose of an API set is to provide an architectural separation from the host DLL in which a given Win32 API is implemented, and the functional contract to which the API belongs. The decoupling that API sets provide between implementation and contracts offers many engineering advantages for developers. In particular, using API sets in your code can improve compatibility with Windows devices.
Are API sets and dlls the same thing?
No—an API set name is a virtual alias for a physical .dll file. It's an implementation-hiding technique, where you as the caller don't have to know exactly which module is hosting the information.
The technique allows modules to be refactored (split apart, consolidated, renamed, and so on) on different Windows versions and editions. And your apps still link, and still get routed to the correct code at runtime.
So why do API sets have .dll in their names? The reason is the way the DLL loader is implemented. The loader is the part of the OS that loads DLLs and/or resolves references to DLLs. And at the front end, the loader requires any string passed to LoadLibrary to be terminated with ".dll". But after that front end, the loader can strip away that suffix, and query the API set database with the resulting string.
LoadLibrary (and delay load) succeeds with an API set name (with the ".dll" in it); but there isn't necessarily an actual file with that name anywhere on the PC.
API set contract names
API sets are identified by a strong contract name that follows these standard conventions recognized by the library loader.

The name must begin either with the string api- or ext-.

Names that begin with api- represent APIs that are guaranteed to exist on all Windows versions.
Names that begin with ext- represent APIs that may not exist on all Windows versions.


The name must end with the sequence l--, where n consists of decimal digits.
The body of the name can be alphanumeric characters, or dashes (-).
The name is case insensitive.

Here are some examples of API set contract names:

api-ms-win-core-ums-l1-1-0
ext-ms-win-com-ole32-l1-1-5
ext-ms-win-ntuser-window-l1-1-0
ext-ms-win-ntuser-window-l1-1-1

You can use an API set name in the context of a loader operation such as LoadLibrary or P/Invoke instead of a DLL module name to ensure a correct route to the implementation no matter where the API is actually implemented on the current device. However, when you do this you must append the string .dll at the end of the contract name. This is a requirement of the loader to function properly, and is not considered actually a part of the contract name. Although contract names appear similar to DLL names in this context, they are fundamentally different from DLL module names and do not directly refer to a file on disk.
Except for appending the string .dll in loader operations, API set contract names should be considered an immutable identifier that corresponds to a specific contract version.

not all this virtual dlls is part of c/c++ runtime

Could you provide some links to Microsoft documentation describing why/when an application would want to distribute these virtual dlls with their application?
